# PowerPoint - Set a time for each slide and display total presentation time?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I know that the transition tabs you can set a time per slide, but this is when you're using it to automatically transition each slide.

What I would like is to have on each slide a time property that I can set.  Then, as the presenter, it would display counting down so that I can see if I am going over/under time on any particular slide when doing my presentation.

In addition, this would be great to be able to determine the total time of the presentation.  So at the bottom tool bar there would be an item for Slide Time = 01:30 and another for Slide Show Time = 05:45

I fear that this is not available, and I think it would be so very very useful to have.

The key point here is that I still want to be in control of the presentation, so I do not want to use the Automatic slide transition.  But I would like to be able to use a value like the slide transition time (and an aggregate of all of those) in order to better prepare and present my shows.

Edit: I found  that I can turn off "Use Timings" in the Slide Show->Set Up area, and this will stop the automatic advancing after each slide while still displaying the time of each slide on the slide show page.  But this doesn't provide me with a slide timer during the presentation, or somewhere to see the aggregate time of the presentation (and if you have 30-45 slides, adding up the time for each slide would be annoying).

Answer (score 1):

There's an Add-in you can download that will give you what you want. Seeing that you have the first part setup, you can use this [Add-in](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/powerpoint/ppt_timer/index.htm) to display the elapsed time on top of the current slide.

There are installation instructions on the website I have linked to, but for convenience I will include them here.

1. Download the executable and let it install the add-in to the default location. I've scanned the executable and the installed Add-in files for viruses and I can confirm that they are clean.
2. Once the Add-in has been installed, open PowerPoint and do the following:

File -> Options -> Add-ins -> (From the Manage drop-down at the bottom) select PowerPoint Add-ins and Go

3. On the resulting dialog do the following:

Add New -> select TM PowerPoint Timer (Ribbon UI) -> OK

The above will add a `TM` tab to the PowerPoint ribbon. On the configuration window for the Timer you'll be able to set a timer to show the Elapsed time. There's also an `Update Display` entry on the first tab, so make sure you set that to 1 second (the default is 10 seconds).

Comment: Thank you, it's close but not what I was hoping for.  This add-on has a 30-day trial and costs $29.95.  More importantly, since the presentation will be given on a computer I don't own, I'm likely not able to install it.

Comment: Hmmmm, that's unfortunate.  As far as I know, there's no option to view the elapsed time on powerpoint by default. Someone else may have a better solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: I found  this, which can provide a total time for the slide show.  It is based on the time set for the automatic transition of the slide (Transitions->Advance Slide->After:).  In the Slide Show ribbon, you can disable "Use Timings" so that you'll have control over advancing the slides while presenting.

This won't provide a slide countdown on the presenter's view, but I suppose I can live without that and just enter the expected time I should be at on the top of my notes.  The add-in above would seem to provide a countdown on the presenter's view, but I won't be able to use it at my venue, so it's not an options.

I based this macro from here, [The PowerPoint FAQ.](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00413_Show_me_the_transition_time_of_each_slide_and_total_running_time_of_the_show.htm)  I have modified it a little bit so to show the times in "00:00" format, and the total time at the bottom instead of separate pop-up. To use it, just create a go to View->Macros, and create a new macro "Total Time".  Copy and paste the code below:

```
Sub TotalTimes()

Dim oSld As Slide
Dim strMessage As String
Dim lngTotalTime As Long
Dim strSlideMin As String
Dim strSlidesec As String


' Use this to collect times for ALL slides:
For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
' Or comment it out and uncomment this to get just the selected slides:
' For Each oSld in ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
    strSlideMin = Format(Int(oSld.SlideShowTransition.AdvanceTime / 60), "00")
    strSlidesec = Format(Int(oSld.SlideShowTransition.AdvanceTime Mod 60), "00")
    strMessage = strMessage _
        & CStr(oSld.SlideNumber) _
        & vbTab _
        & strSlideMin & ":" & strSlidesec _
        & vbCrLf
    lngTotalTime = lngTotalTime + oSld.SlideShowTransition.AdvanceTime
Next oSld

' Comment these out if you don't want to see them
strMessage = strMessage & vbCrLf & "Total" & vbTab & Format(Int(lngTotalTime / 60), "00") & ":" & Format(Int(lngTotalTime Mod 60), "00")
MsgBox strMessage
'MsgBox ("Total time: " & CStr(lngTotalTime))


End Sub
```

The original code also includes a section to write to a text file, which I cut out since it didn't meet my needs.

I am so very very surprised MS doesn't have this info available within PowerPoint.  It seems like a rather intuitive bit of information that they would include by default.

Comment: Nice. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

There are more elegant ways of doing this via an add-in but how about this ... it assumes you're using presenter view, where you can see the notes, but you could add the text to the slide or whatever instead.

```
Option Explicit
Public StartTime As Date

Sub StartTimer()
    StartTime = Time
    SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide (SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex + 1)
End Sub

Sub ElapsedTime(osh As Shape)

    Dim oNotesText As Shape
    Dim oNextSlide As Slide

    ' what slide are we about to move TO?
    Set oNextSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(osh.Parent.SlideIndex + 1)

    ' Get a reference to the notes text on that slide (not 100% reliable, but generally works)
    Set oNotesText = oNextSlide.NotesPage.Shapes(2)

    ' Do the time math and add the elapsed time to the notes:
    With oNotesText
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(Time - StartTime, "HH:MM:SS") & vbCrLf & .TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    End With

    ' And go to the slide
    SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide (SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex + 1)

End Sub
```

Add a shape to the first slide and assign it an Action Setting of Run Macro: StartTimer
Add a shape to the next slide, assign it an Action Setting of Run Macro: ElapsedTime
Copy and paste the shape from slide 2 to the other slides in the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on this page: [link](http://nygma.hu/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2935:go-live-countdown-timer-in-powerpoint&catid=38&Itemid=65). The author creates a count-down timer in memory, and adds its progress text to the last shape inserted in every slide.

I modified it a bit to not affect the first slide, and to update the shape before last inserted; I always remove the date and slide number from the footer and then add them when the presentation is final.

To set the number of minutes to count-down from, find `TargetDateTime = DateAdd("n", 6, Now)` and modify the `6`.

Here's my modified code:

```
Option Explicit
'API Declarations
Declare PtrSafe Function SetTimer Lib "user32" _
                            (ByVal hwnd As LongLong, _
                             ByVal nIDEvent As LongLong, _
                             ByVal uElapse As LongLong, _
                             ByVal lpTimerFunc As LongLong) As LongLong
Declare PtrSafe Function KillTimer Lib "user32" _
                            (ByVal hwnd As LongLong, _
                             ByVal nIDEvent As LongLong) As LongLong

' Public Variables
Public TimerID As LongLong
Public bTimerState As Boolean
Public TargetDateTime As Date


Sub TimerOnOff()

Dim maxshapes As Integer
Dim i As Integer

TargetDateTime = DateAdd("n", 6, Now)

For i = 2 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    maxshapes = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes.Count
    ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(maxshapes - 1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ""
Next i

If bTimerState = False Then
    TimerID = SetTimer(0, 0, 1000, AddressOf TimerProc)
    If TimerID = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Unable to create the timer", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    bTimerState = True
    SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide (SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex + 1)
Else
    TimerID = KillTimer(0, TimerID)
    If TimerID = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Unable to stop the timer", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
    End If
    bTimerState = False
End If

End Sub

' The defined routine gets called every nnnn milliseconds.
Sub TimerProc(ByVal hwnd As LongLong, _
                    ByVal uMsg As LongLong, _
                    ByVal idEvent As LongLong, _
                    ByVal dwTime As LongLong)

Dim diff As Date
Dim out As String
Dim maxshapes As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Dim hours As String
Dim minutes As String
Dim seconds As String

Dim hoursTest As Boolean
Dim minutesTest As Boolean
Dim secondsTest As Boolean

diff = TargetDateTime - Now
out = ""

hoursTest = (Hour(diff) <> 0)
minutesTest = (Minute(diff) <> 0)
secondsTest = (Second(diff) <> 0)

hours = CStr(Hour(diff))
minutes = CStr(Minute(diff))
seconds = CStr(Second(diff))

If hoursTest Then
    If Hour(diff) < 10 Then
        out = out + "0"
    End If
    out = out + hours
End If

If minutesTest Or hoursTest Then
    If hoursTest Then
        out = out + ":"
    End If
    If Minute(diff) < 10 Then
        out = out + "0"
    End If
    out = out + minutes
End If

If secondsTest Or minutesTest Then
    If minutesTest Then
        out = out + ":"
    End If
    If Second(diff) < 10 Then
        out = out + "0"
    End If
    out = out + seconds
Else
    If minutesTest And hoursTest Then
        out = "END"
    End If
End If

On Error GoTo err:
For i = 2 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    maxshapes = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes.Count
    ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(maxshapes - 1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = out
Next i
err:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a comment on the macro pulled from the The PowerPoint FAQ above. It is very useful, but not quite adequate. I used the original version to try to work out why slides did not synchronise correctly with some music tracks.

After removing (most of) the schoolboy errors it became clear what was missing. Each slide had a 1 second transition to the next. For tracks with few slides the extra time was 'lost' but for longer tracks these extra seconds became noticable.

There was another problem. On some of the slides the total duration of the animations was longer than slide advance time, which added to the delays (that was the overlooked schoolboy error). So at least one extra line is required in the macro:

```
strMessage = strMessage _
    & CStr(oSld.SlideNumber) _
    & vbTab _
    **& CStr(oSld.SlideShowTransition.Duration) _
    & vbTab _**
    & CStr(oSld.SlideShowTransition.AdvanceTime) _
    & vbCrLf
```

to add an extra column to the table showing the duration of the transition, and an amendment to show to include the duration in the total time:
lngTotalTime = lngTotalTime + oSld.SlideShowTransition.AdvanceTime **+ oSld.SlideShowTransition.Duration**
Perhaps however you would prefer to see the totals of these two elements separately.

I have not addressed the animation durations greater than the total advancetime on a slide, but it does occur to me that it would be useful to include in the message the total time of each animation, including their delay times in the report, for any excess over the advance time will increase the length of the slide show, but is also likely to have been unintended.